# How do I step into UIKit Source files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

When looking at some code answers here on StackOverflow it looks like people are able to step into the UIKit source files.

However, when I try to do that I only see what looks like assembly code.

How do I step in to the source so I can see the more detailed code comments that might help me?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot step into the UIKit source. It is, as you rightly say, visible during debugging only as assembler. You don't have the source. (It's secret.)

What you can do is view the Objective-C *header* files. For example, if you Control-Command-click on the term UIView in your code, you jump to the header file, and if you want to see it in the original Objective-C, choose Original Source from the Related Items menu. The headers do indeed often contain comments or other information that can prove more useful / correct than the documentation, plus they just constitute, of themselves, an excellent conspectus of a class etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is giff representation how you can do that ... Step into header files by `Command + click` on whose definition you want to see

[image]

Comment: Aside from the pretty pictures, how is that different from what I said?

Comment: Its just graphical visuals that can help him understand better ...